# Definition of a Elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I've seen two different definitions of an elliptic curve.

1) The first one being that it is a nonsingular projective curve of genus 1.

2) The other definition nonsingular projective curve of dimension 1.

I'm unsure whether these two definitions are the same? In case they are, can someone explain why?

In curves dimension=genus?

Maybe this is wrong, I cannot remember where I saw the "definition" 2.

Comment: a curve is by definition of dimension 1. so the second one must be a printing mistake or something like that. first one is the definition.

Answer (score 7):

Definition 2 is wrong. Any curve has dimension 1.

Strictly speaking, definition 1 is also wrong. You need also a base point on the curve to have an elliptic curve; otherwise you just have a genus $1$ curve.

Alternatively, an elliptic curve is an *abelian variety of dimension $1$*, i.e. an abelian variety which is also a curve. Such a curve necessarily has genus $1$, and is an elliptic curve in the sense of the other definition. The reason for which it must have genus $1$ is essentially because the fundamental group of a topological group is always abelian, and a genus $g$ surface has abelian fundamental group only for $g=0$ and $g=1$; the $g=0$ case is ruled out by the Hairy Ball Theorem (which implies that there is no smooth group structure on the $2$-sphere).

Comment: you don't need to specify a base point to define an elliptic curve. only genus 1 is sufficient. the base point can be chosen using Riemann-Roch.

Comment: See R.Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Chapter IV, Examples $1.3.6, 1.3.7$

Comment: @Krish By almost all conventions, an elliptic curve is an abelian variety of dimension 1. In particular, it comes equipped with a base point.

Comment: @Krish See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime and consider $X^3+pY^3+p^2Z^3\subset \mathbb{P^2_{\mathbb{Q}}}$ then this has no rational point (just look mod $p$). Obviously if you are over an algebraically closed field the condition becomes redundant though.

Comment: @sdf What you are saying is that that genus $1$ curve over Q has no rational point, so it cannot be made into an elliptic curve over Q.

Comment: The definition of an elliptic curve doesn't say that there *exists some* rational point. The rational point $0$ belongs to the *data*.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I needed some backup here

Comment: @Bruno: I am agreeing with you... my example shows that you do not always have a rational point as was claimed...

Comment: @sdf Ah ok! All good then.

Comment: Another nice way of seeing that $g=1$, assuming that we're talking about elliptic curves over fields, is that all algebraic groups over fields are 'parallelizable'. They have trivial cotangent bundle. So, by Riemann-Roch, if $C/k$ is a curve with group structure, then $0=\deg \Omega_{C/k}=2g-2$, so $g=1$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis  You can also use the Lefschetz trace formula. The compactly supported Euler characteristic of an algebraic group over a field $k$  equals the trace of $t_a$ on $\ell$-adic cohomology (with $a \in E(\bar k)$ nonzero). This trace equals zero as there are no fixed points.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar This is the way that, for example, Milne suggests to do it. It just seems way, way too hard in general though. :) I guess it's nice since we can imitate a topological proof here. It's a bummer that there is no immediate analogue for Bruno's proof with the fundamental group, since $\pi_1^{\text{et}}(G)$ needn't be abelian if $G$ is an algebraic group.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the comment. I agree that the Lefschetz trace argument isn't necessarily easier. :)